# How to install PhpMyAdmin on Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, debian

I am new on Debian, and I want to install PhpMyAdmin with graphical interface. I know I have to use XAMPP.

When I searched on Internet how to install PhpMyAdmin, I saw many answers and videos about it, but every answer told a different way from one another and all tutorial I followed failed. I was very frustrating.
Now, I have uninstall Php, Mysql, XAMPP and PhpMyAdmin.

Can you help me to install it correctly?

Thanks

Comment: XAMPP already contains PhpMyAdmin. Just point your browser to http://localhost/phpmyadmin if it is installed and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP already contains PhpMyAdmin. Just point your browser to http://localhost/phpmyadmin if it is installed and running.

But if XAMPP is not installed yet, you don't need it at all. There is a package for PhpMyAdmin in Debian repo. Just do:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and say "Yes" to the installation and this will install all dependencies you need, including PHP and MySQL.

If yo decide to use XAMPP, then all you need is contained in it. A MySQL server and a PHP interpreter, as well as Apache and all requisites. You just have to install it and start it correctly. I don't suggest you to use XAMPP. Installing the packages of your distribution is much better.

If you have any doubts, you may read [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-debian-7). It is about Debian 7, but the installation procedures are all the same.

Comment: I follow the tutorial and installed mysql-server and phpmyadmin. I added the "Include" at the end of the apache configuration file. But now, when I go on localhost/phpmyadmin, it is written: "You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server."

Comment: I was using the wlan0 inet adr and that was a mistake because, when I used the lo inet adr it works :) Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. This is why we are here at StackOverflow.